# Using Kal calendar without doing the initialization (and so on) in the AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, calendar

I'm using the [Kal calendar](http://github.com/klazuka/Kal). For the code shown below I'm referring to the Holiday example. In this example the allocation and initialization of Kal is done in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` in the `AppDelegate`. The `UITableViewDelegate` protocol (e.g. `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`) is also positioned in the `AppDelegate` class.

The `AppDelegate`:

```
#import "HolidayAppDelegate.h"
#import "HolidaySqliteDataSource.h"
#import "HolidaysDetailViewController.h"
## Heading ###import "Kal.h"

@implementation HolidayAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
  kal = [[KalViewController alloc] init];

  kal.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Today" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showAndSelectToday)] autorelease];
  kal.delegate = self;
  dataSource = [[HolidaySqliteDataSource alloc] init];
  kal.dataSource = dataSource;

  // Setup the navigation stack and display it.
  navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:kal];
  [window addSubview:navController.view];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

// Action handler for the navigation bar's right bar button item.
- (void)showAndSelectToday
{
  [kal showAndSelectDate:[NSDate date]];
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate protocol conformance

// Display a details screen for the selected holiday/row.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  Holiday *holiday = [dataSource holidayAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  HolidaysDetailViewController *vc = [[[HolidaysDetailViewController alloc] initWithHoliday:holiday] autorelease];
  [navController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark -

- (void)dealloc
{
  [kal release];
  [dataSource release];
  [window release];
  [navController release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I don't want to put this into the `AppDelegate`, because there could be some overlapping code with other views. It should be a separate "component" which I can call and put on the stack.

In my navigation based project I have a main view, the `RootViewController`. From there I want to push the Kal view on the stack. Currently I'm pushing an additional `ViewController` on the stack. In the `viewWillAppear` method from this `ViewController` I do the things shown in the code above. The following problems appear:

- Navigation back has to be done two times (one for the Kal calendar, one for my created view)
- Navigation to my main view is not possible anymore

In the moment I don't know where to put this code. So the question is where to put the methods for allocation/initialization as well as the methods for the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol.

**Solution:**

```
if (kal == nil) {
    kal = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
    kal.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Timetable",@"");
    kal.delegate = self;
    self.dataSource = [[[MyDataSource alloc] init] autorelease];
    kal.dataSource = dataSource;
}
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:kal animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done the initialization in my `RootViewController`. This isn't the best solution, but I didn't found another one.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to read the SimpleEKDemo example from Apple.

Comment: It should be ported to other controller other than AppDelegate by following the logic of the example. For iPhone application, porting to RootViewController is good. For iPad application with UISplitViewController, it could be ported to either masterViewController or DetailViewController. Cheer.